# Monitoring Thread Execution

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, executorservice

I have below code where first I am creating an on demand db connection and then sharing it with multiple threads. This is working fine. Now, I wanted to know if it is possible to track whether all the threads using this database connection have finished execution so that I can close the database connection. Any guidance on how I can achieve this will be helpful.

```
    Connection connection = null;
    Properties connectionProperties = getProperties();

    for (int reqIdx = 0; reqIdx < requests.length(); reqIdx++) { 
            connection = DBonnection.getConnection(connectionProperties); 
            ConnectorRunner connectorRunner = null;
            try {
                connectorRunner = new ConnectorRunner(someConnector);               
                connectorRunner.setDBConnection(connection);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            executorService.execute(connectorRunner);
    }
```

Comment: Sharing a single dababase connections between multiple threads is a bad, bad idea. How would you handle transactions? Use a connection pool.

Comment: Seconding @JBNizet, Checkout  Apache dbcp https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

Comment: The connection is on demand based on user's properties at runtime, thus I can not create connection pool. I am sharing the connection because threads will use connection in a sequential way using synchronized load.

Comment: On demand connections is the whole point of a connection pool. Why do you think you cannot use a connection pool?

Comment: @JimGarrison I will get the connection properties at runtime. That's the reason I cannot create connection pool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is using a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) from the standard JDK facilities. In your main thread do

```
CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(requests.length());

for (Request req : requests) {
  ConnectorRunner connectorRunner = new ConnectorRunner(doneSignal);
  connectorRunner.setConnection(DBonnection.getConnection());
  executorService.execute(connectorRunner);
}

doneSignal.await();
DBonnection.dispose();
```

The ConnectorRunner must simply call `doneSignal.countDown()` when it's done.

Comment: I was looking for something like this. Worked perfectly!! Many thanks @Raffaele

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the above comments, if you are looking to do something when all your threads are finished, you can take either of the below approach.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    es.execute(new Runnable() { /*  your task */ });
es.shutdown();
boolean finshed = es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
// all tasks have finished or the time has been reached.
```

OR

```
for (Thread thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
}
```

Please note that second approach will block the current thread.

Comment: This is a good answer, but please format your code correctly.

Comment: My bad, will do. Stackoverflow should have auto format code feature. :)

Comment: @Anil Thanks. In my approach I cannot shutdown the executor service as more requests will be coming and I only need to track the set of threads using a same db connection instance and close the connection once they have finished execution.

Comment: Then use connection pooling - DBCP or C3P0. That would take care of your concerns. You can define max active, max wait, max idle, initial connections and other properties

Comment: And first approach will also block current thread for maximum 1 minutes